# C# Record Types: Equality comparisons between record sub-classes

Tags: c#, record, equality

Given a parent record type:

```
public record Foo(string Value);
```

And two record sub-classes `Bar` and `Bee` I wonder if it is possible to implement `Equals` in the base class so as instances of Foo, Bar or Bee are all considered *equal* based on `Value` (both with `Equals` and `==`).

I tried the following after digesting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records, but it didn't quite work:

```cs
    public record Foo(string Value)
    {
        public virtual bool Equals(Foo? other)
        {
            return other != null && this.Value == other.Value;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => this.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public record Bar(string Value) : Foo(Value)
    {
        protected override Type EqualityContract => typeof(Foo);
    }

    public record Bee(string Value) : Foo(Value)
    {
        protected override Type EqualityContract => typeof(Foo);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestFooBar()
    {
        Assert.That(new Foo("foo") == new Bar("foo"), Is.True); // Passes
        Assert.That(new Bar("foo") == new Foo("foo"), Is.True); // Fails!
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestFooBee()
    {
        Assert.That(new Foo("foo") == new Bee("foo"), Is.True); // Passes
        Assert.That(new Bee("foo") == new Foo("foo"), Is.True); // Fails!
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestBarBee()
    {
        Assert.That(new Bar("foo") == new Bee("foo"), Is.True); // Fails!
        Assert.That(new Bee("foo") == new Bar("foo"), Is.True); // Fails!
    }
```

**This question is specific to record types**. I don't need an example with classes (I know that already).

When I look at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoTCDMACAJwFMBjAewIBM8AxMsgCgRQAY8A1CAGwFciBKTAG9MeMXlx4AblAIAXHtzzB6XPAFEAjoq4BnBnTIB+PGTkALIgUEZxeEbbviEAdlMWreAIQBePDB4uNQAyYLwLKF0AOk5eIjwfPzNLAhjuPgBuUXEAX0xssUkyKSsCKEp42Dk8AHEiOQAJCF1zAGEyCoZ+BIA+cPNItLiousbmto6iLqyMPKwMSWJyKjwAIQgCJlYOdIE8EFp6Bli+Gwc7AAcCM1I5Impi0vL4gBUATwv4rR0oOTf2mByAgQEjVHx9P6fMgAMwM9H4Mzm2HwSwo1FWRCmzDYJz2B0Mx12ZwKeCuN1B91MJQIZQqeHenw02m4v3+ZEBwNBvXCHyIMLhZARmByQA===),  I see the following implementation for `Bar`:

```cs
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Bar);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public sealed override bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        return Equals((object)other);
    }
```

And in `Foo`:

```cs
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public static bool operator ==(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        if ((object)left != right)
        {
            if ((object)left != null)
            {
                return left.Equals(right);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Foo);
    }
    
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public virtual bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if (other != null)
        {
            return Value == other.Value;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So naturally new `Bar("foo") == new Bee("foo")` would end-up calling `Bar.Equals(Foo?)`, which is synthetic and relies on `Bar.Equals(object)` which will cast to `Bar` or return null, and because a `Bee` is not a `Bar` it ends-up comparing null.

It doesn't seem possible to override some of the synthetic Equals methods so it seems I cannot escape this behavior.

Or, can I?

NOTE: I'm on .NET SDK 6.0.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. According to the draft spec, (a) `bool Equals(Base? other)` may not be declared explicitly (and calls `Equals(object)`), (b) `bool Equals(object? obj)` may not be declared explicitly, and (c) the latter always calls `Equals(obj as R)`, yielding `null` in your case. Sorry, I wasn't able to find a loop-hole.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm a bit surprised that one of the corollaries is that even when overriding `EqualityContract`, the synthetic method implementation will result in a non-commutative `==` between parents and children, and I wonder if that is intended, since it seems it defeats the purpose of having that `EqualityContract` property overridable.

Comment: If Foos, Bars and Bees are all considered equal based on their values, aren't they all just Foos? Why do you need multiple classes? And if they have different behavior (in their other methods), why do you want them to behave as if they're equal?

Comment: `Foos`, `Bars` and `Beers` may have different properties and behaviors yet want to have the same object identity, which is not the same as _behaving as if they're equal_.

Even if your question makes sense this is more about understanding equality of a c# feature (records) and less about how to design class hierarchies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the stack trace when calling `new Bar("foo") == new Foo("foo")`:

```
at Foo.Equals(Foo other)
at Bar.Equals(Bar other)
at Bar.Equals(Object obj)
at Bar.Equals(Foo other)
at Foo.op_Equality(Foo r1, Foo r2)
```

According to the [draft spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#equality-members), you cannot declare any of those methods explicitly (i.e. do not have control over them) except `Foo.Equals(Foo)` and `Bar.Equals(Bar)`, at which point `other` has already been (unsuccessfully) casted to `Bar`, in `Bar.Equals(Object)`.

Though it is not totally impossible - you can declare the operators `==(Bar, Foo)`, `!=(Bar, Foo)` etc manually, and let operator overload resolution pick your operator, instead of the `==(Foo, Foo)` one, which you have no control over. But this is quite tedious to do for all the types, and you'd still have the problem of `Bar.Equals(Foo)` not working the way you want. :(

`EqualityContract` is rather irrelevant. It is only checked in the generated `Foo.Equals(Foo)`,

> The synthesized `Equals(R?)` returns true if and only if each of the following are true:
>
> - [...]
> - If there is a base record type, the value of `base.Equals(other)` (a non-virtual call to `public virtual bool Equals(Base? other)`); otherwise the value of `EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract`.

but at that point `other` is null already! Not to mention that you wrote your own `Foo.Equals(Foo)`, so the `EqualityContract`s are not used at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it again confirms that it is not possible to do what I was asking.

> EqualityContract is rather irrelevant. It is only checked in the generated Foo.Equals(Foo).

This is also true, thanks for pointing that out.

Nevertheless I'm curious because I don't see much of a point using `EqualityContract` if the `==` breaks symmetry when comparing parent instances against child instances.

My conclusion so far is: _Don't mess with equality in record types, if you feel the urge... use classes instead..._