# Equality of interface types implemented by records

Tags: c#, record

Let's say I got the record

```cs
public sealed record Person(int Id, string GivenName, string Surname)
{
  // imagine a few non-trivial methods here
}
```

I got other code that deals with `Person`s that I want to unit-test. Because I don't want to have to construct exactly the right instances to make the methods return what the tests need, I introduce an interface:

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
  int Id { get; }
  // pulled up all the non-trivial methods from Person
}
```

and add `IEntity` to the interface implementation list of `Person`.

However, somewhere in code depending on `IEntity`s, I need to check two instances for equality:

```cs
[Test]
public void Repro()
{
    // arrange
    IEntity lhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");
    IEntity rhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");
    // act
    var result = lhs == rhs;
    // assert
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

The assertion fails. Because while `Person` implicitly defines an `operator==`, there is none for `IEntity`, so the default implementation is used which in turn relies on `object.Equals()` which uses *reference equality*.

And there is no way for me to define that missing `operator==(IEntity, IEntity)`:

In `Person`, I cannot define it because at least one of the two operands must be `Person`.

In `IEntity`, I cannot define it because, well, I cannot implement static methods (even with C#11 I could only define it abstractly).

So that makes implementing interfaces with records rather dangerous because the intuitive assumption one would make is not correct. Which leaves only not using an interface, but that again makes writing tests for code depending on the behavior of `Person` very tedious.

Am I overlooking something here?
Or how else can I abstract `Person` such that it makes testing dependent code easy while not introducing that subtle issue?

Comment: How does GetHashCode behave in your case ?

Comment: Thinking that `==` would just work on some random interfaces is not intuitive to me at all. Why did you think that in the first place? Keep in mind that these are interfaces - you are not *supposed* to know that they are implemented by a record.

Comment: How about just calling `Equals` instead?

Comment: @Sweeper in general, I would agree with that notion - but usually it doesn't bug me that I have to add `IEquatable<IEntity>` to the interface and then `.Equals()` instead of ==, in this instance it does because the interface really just exists to make my unit-testing life easier.

However, that has been my solution in the real-world code that led to post this question here.

Comment: @Irwene: I was interested what happens when I put IEntity into a dictionary as key - not so much because of the hashcode, but because at some points a dictionary will have to perform equality checks, too, and my assumption was that for the interface it would fall back to default object equality == refererence equality.
However, to my pleasant surprise, a `Dictionary<IEntity, int>` works correctly: when I add two structurally equal `Person` instances, I get a duplicate key exception.

Comment: Dictionary uses `GetHashCode` + `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` by default, which uses a passthrough call to `.Equals` (i.e., `==` is never used in a dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

A few points.

> the default implementation is used which in turn relies on `object.Equals()` which uses *reference equality*.

This is not correct. Reference equality is checked with `object.ReferenceEquals`

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records),

> It is an error if the [==, !=] operators are declared explicitly.

And the same for `Equals`.

I think your question is more or less a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508962/c-sharp-record-types-equality-comparisons-between-record-sub-classes) which says it's not possible to do what you want.

Having said that, why can't you call `.Equals`, which seems to do what you want?

```cs
public sealed record Person(int Id, string GivenName, string Surname) : IEntity
{
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEntity lhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");
        IEntity rhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");

        var result = lhs == rhs;
        var resultEquals = object.Equals(lhs, rhs);
        var resultRefEquals = object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs);

        Console.WriteLine($"result: {result}, resultEquals: {resultEquals}, resultRefEquals: {resultRefEquals}");
    }
}
```

console out:

```
result: False, resultEquals: True, resultRefEquals: False
```

Comment: see my own answer, mostly my annoyance was "I'm introducing that interface solely to facilitate testing and all of a sudden I gotta change consumer code (other than just the referenced type) because there's no way to say "hey, this interface defines that any implementations use record-like member-equality."

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper pointed out correctly in the comments, there is currently no good way to specify for an interface how the equality operator should behave.

So my solution is to make `IEntity` extend `IEquatable<IEntity>` and depend on the `.Equals()`method from that interface - the idea being that if someone sees an interface implementing `IEquatable<>`, they know what to do.

I guess in the end my feeling of discontent stems really just from the fact that there is no way to specify in the interface that operator== and its inverse are to work per-member and having that requirement automatically fulfilled by a record.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a base record class instead of an interface. I had the same issue (that's how I found this answer) and figured out that the comparisons will work if you use a base class (which can be empty!). Bear in mind that all properties will be compared, even the ones in the implementing class. So try this:

```
public record Base
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public sealed record Person(int Id, string GivenName, string Surname) : Base
{
    // imagine a few non-trivial methods here
}

[Test]
public void Repro1()
{
    // arrange
    Base lhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");
    Base rhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");
    // act
    var result = lhs == rhs;
    // assert
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}

[Test]
public void Repro2()
{
    // arrange
    Base lhs = new Person(1, "John", "Doe");
    Base rhs = new Person(1, "John", "Smith");
    // act
    var result = lhs == rhs;
    // assert
    result.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

Bear in mind that the comparison is made on all object properties (check my Repro2), not just on the `Id` property from the base class. Also, I haven't tested this particular code, but I'm using a similar example in my code. Lastly, Lists and Dicts don't play well with record comparisons, as their default comparison operator is `Equals` instead of `SequenceEqual`, so you might want to consider that if you are using them in your records.